# Rspec equal method

Tags: ruby, rspec

From what I have understood, the equal method checks if the object is the same.

```
person = Person.create!(:name => "David")
Person.find_by_name("David").should equal(person)
```

This should be true.

But aren't there two different objects here?

How could two objects be the same? I don't understand that.

Comment: Which two different objects are you referring to?

Comment: @jtbandes: in the first line an object is returned which "person" will be referred to. in the second line an object is returned to and this object should be equal to the person. so aren't that two objects?

Comment: Either a) the exact same object could be returned; or b) the second object could be equal (by its own `equal?` or other method) to the first, like having the same properties (in this case, `name`). Read the ActiveRecord::Base docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`equal` checks if the reference is the same. It corresponds to the `Object#equal?` method. You want to use `==` to compare these objects.

Answer (score 38):

Rails and RSpec equality tests have a variety of choices.

Rails 3.2 ActiveRecord::Base uses the `==` equality matcher.

It returns true two different ways:

- If `self` is the same exact object as the comparison object
- If `self` is the same type as the comparison object and has the same ID

Note that ActiveRecord::Base has the `==` method which is aliased as `eql?`. This is different than typical Ruby objects, which define `==` and `eql?` differently.

RSpec 2.0 has these equality matchers in rspec-expectations:

```
a.should equal(b) # passes if a.equal?(b)
a.should eql(b) # passes if a.eql?(b)
a.should == b # passes if a == b
```

RSpec also has two equality matchers intended to have more of a DSL feel to them:

```
a.should be(b) # passes if a.equal?(b)
a.should eq(b) # passes if a == b
```

In your example you're creating a record then finding it.

So you have two choices for testing `#find_by_name`:

- To test if it retrieves the exact same object *OR* an equivalent Person record with the same ID, then use `should ==` or its equivalent `a.should eql` or its DSL version `should eq`
- To test if it uses the exact same object *NOT* an equivalent Person record with the same ID, then use `should equal` or its DSL version `should be`

Comment: `==` and `eql` are not equivalent: `2 == 2.0 and not 2.eql? 2.0`

Comment: Thanks Aaron, good point. I'm updating the answer to clarify that ActiveRecord::Base does make them equivalent, which is different than Ruby's typical usage.

Comment: Thanks @joelparkerhenderson.  This is the most useful overview of Ruby equality I've seen.