# Testing rails controller with rspec: value is same, but object id is different

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I try to test a rails controller with rspec like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe NewsController do  
  describe "GET 'edit'" do
    before(:each) do
      @news_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:news_1)
      get :edit, { :id => @news_1.id }
    end
    it { response.should be_success }
    it { assigns(:news).should eq(@news_1) }
    it { response.should render_template(:edit) }
  end
end
```

But, I got this error.

```
    Failures:

  1) NewsController GET 'edit' 
     Failure/Error: it { assigns(:news).should eq(@news_1) }

       expected: #<News id: 1, title: "news_title_1", contents: "news_contents_1", display: nil, created_at: "2012-11-29 07:24:49", updated_at: "2012-11-29 07:24:49", news_date: nil, orion: false, pw: false, op: false, pickup: false, info_1: nil, info_2: nil, info_3: nil, info_4: nil, info_5: nil, del: false, place: nil, contact: false>
            got: #<News id: 1, title: "news_title_1", contents: "news_contents_1", display: nil, created_at: "2012-11-29 07:24:49", updated_at: "2012-11-29 07:24:49", news_date: nil, orion: false, pw: false, op: false, pickup: false, info_1: nil, info_2: nil, info_3: nil, info_4: nil, info_5: nil, del: false, place: nil, contact: false>

       (compared using ==)

       Diff:#<News:0x000001030b55c8>.==(#<News:0x000001033126b8>) returned false even though the diff between #<News:0x000001030b55c8> and #<News:0x000001033126b8> is empty. Check the implementation of #<News:0x000001030b55c8>.==.
     # ./spec/controllers/news_controller_spec.rb:73:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I think these values are same, but object id is different.
So this test fails... 
How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem myself. My workaround was comparing the attributes, i.e.

```
it { assigns(:news).attributes.should eq(News.last.attributes) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is how the 'eq' does the comparison between two objects. you might want to use == in this scenario. You can see a detailed explanation in this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436234/rspec-equal-method)

Comment: Thanks. I used '=='. but i got the same error. How do I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

you should do as follow

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe NewsController do  
  describe "GET 'edit'" do
    before(:each) do
      @news_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:news_1)
      get :edit, { :id => @news_1.id }
    end
    it { response.should be_success }
    it { assigns(:news).should eq(News.last) }
    it { response.should render_template(:edit) }
  end
end
```

== and eq are different. To test your method when it retrieves the object, then use should == or its equivalent a.should eql

Comment: Thanks. I used '=='. but i got the same error. How do I solve this error?

Comment: I tried. but I got the error again. I think these values are same, but object id is different. I don't know why object id changed unexpectedly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem comparing an array and I solved it with:

```
expect(assigns(:receipts)).to match_array(receipts)
```